# Boot sector of the Linux kernel (vmlinuz) in x86 system with bzImage format

Tags: linux-kernel, partition

Using a HEX viewer, I am looking at the vmlinuz Linux kernel 3.14.28 in X86 architecture which is in the bzImage format. The boot sector of the file looks like this:

[image]

It defines two partitions: partition 1 with Ext2 file system of size 18.9 GB which is active and an extended partition with no logical partitions inside. Does this mean that Linux kernel assumes that the user has created these two partitions on his system? Why Linux kernel has defined these two partitions?

Comment: Your HEX viewer seems great may I ask you which one you use ?

Comment: @A.Meau: Disk editor. You can download it from here: http://www.disk-editor.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This block of data is mostly a relict from the days when Linux was booted from floppies and didn't need a boot loader. It is indeed a boot sector, but the real mode x86 code, when executed, just says "Use a boot loader. Remove the disk and press any key to reboot".

The data at the end is not a partition table, but the space at the end was used to convey settings like the VGA mode, the root device and some flags to the kernel. If you study the values a little closer you'll see they make no sense as a partition table.

The boot block still has some meaning, though, which is why I said "mostly" above. The start of the file is carefully crafted to also look like a UEFI application, which enables the kernel itself to function as its own boot loader. The file starts with the magic string MZ (just like a DOS .exe), and contains a PE/COFF header.